# Understanding a Program In Assembly

Tags: assembly

I am trying to understand part of a program in assembly that I don't really get.  Can someone explain how some of these lines of code work? 
I read that the code .long num means a long with that value, but this seams like it isn't the case.
Thanks!

```
 nums:   // storing an array of numbers
     .long 1 + 3   // Does this mean that we are soring the number 4 in nums?  
     .long 2 * 12  //storing 24?
     .long 0x3 | 0x772   //  storing one or another hexidecmial number?  
     .long 4     // storing the number 4? 
     .long 5     // storing the number 5 

 .equ size, 5 # #define size 5
```

Comment: which architecture and assembler is that? tag them properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, **.long**  tells the assembler to reserve 4-bytes of memory. Then, evaluate the expression given as argument and initialize this memory location with the result.

In your example the value at location **nums** will be *4*, at **nums+4** will be *24* at **nums+8** the *Bitwise Logical OR* (the operator |) between the two hex values etc.

So it perfectly makes sense as an array of numbers (as your comment says), since there are some numbers stored in successive memory locations.